# a PRINT 'Success' that screw up a begin trans/ begin try commit / end try?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

So I just saw a weird behavior

In one script there is something like:

```
  begin transaction
  begin try

       stuff
       stuff
       stuff

       print 'commit'
       commit transaction
  end try
  begin catch
       print 'rollback'
       print error_message()
       rollback transaction
  end catch
```

thing is when this script in run, I see the print commit message but it does not make the commit and lock the tables/rows/etc

I have to manually run a commit by selecting the line and run it.

but if I do this

```
 begin transaction
  begin try

       stuff
       stuff
       stuff

       commit transaction
       print 'commit'
  end try
  begin catch
       print error_message()
       rollback transaction
       print 'rollback'
  end catch
```

(swapped the print and the commit)

it work fine.

anyone know why this would happen?

Comment: both scripts print commit on our sql2005 server?! (I had to comment the `print @@error_message()` though)

Comment: `@@error_message()` should be `ERROR_MESSAGE()` (when in a CATCH block)

Comment: @KM - found it already but it does show that OP didn't run these scripts. He deserves a spanking ;)

Comment: I just typed kind of speudo sql code by memory, I don't have the real script with me

Comment: @Lieven, I've done the same thing.  when working on a script, doing test runs, it is easy to cause this if you are always running parts of the script.  If you only highlight the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and some code that does not include a ROLLBACK or COMMIT and run it you get the hanging transaction.  When you try to run the whole thing, you need that extra COMMIT to get @@TRANCOUNT back to zero.

Comment: I guessed that much. For the record, I was (trying to) making a joke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works fine for me:

```
--create table t (rowid int)  --create one time before running script

begin transaction
  begin try

       insert into t values (1)
       print 'commit'
       print XACT_STATE()   --should be 1
       commit transaction
       print XACT_STATE()   --should be 0
  end try
  begin catch
       print ERROR_MESSAGE()
       rollback transaction
       print 'rollback'
  end catch

select * from t
```

output

```
commit
1
0
rowid
-----------
1
```

Close your SSMS window, open a new window, and then run your 1st script again, I'll bet you had an open transaction the first time you ran it, so you needed that extra COMMIT.

**EDIT** after OP comment:

run this exact script in a new connection to each database:

```
BEGIN TRY create table t (rowid int) END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH

print 'A - XACT_STATE()='+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),XACT_STATE()),'')+', @@TRANCOUNT='+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),@@TRANCOUNT),'')

begin transaction
  begin try

       insert into t values (1)
       print 'commit'
       print 'B - XACT_STATE()='+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),XACT_STATE()),'')+', @@TRANCOUNT='+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),@@TRANCOUNT),'')
       commit transaction
       print 'C - XACT_STATE()='+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),XACT_STATE()),'')+', @@TRANCOUNT='+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),@@TRANCOUNT),'')
  end try
  begin catch
       print ERROR_MESSAGE()
       rollback transaction
       print 'rollback'
  end catch

print 'D - XACT_STATE()='+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),XACT_STATE()),'')+', @@TRANCOUNT='+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),@@TRANCOUNT),'')

select * from t
```

you should get this:

```
A - XACT_STATE()=0, @@TRANCOUNT=0

(1 row(s) affected)
commit
B - XACT_STATE()=1, @@TRANCOUNT=1
C - XACT_STATE()=0, @@TRANCOUNT=0
D - XACT_STATE()=0, @@TRANCOUNT=0
rowid
-----------
1

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: I just asked and the first script run fine on the dev server but not on the prod server, the prod server must use the second script